# Sine of 360 degrees is coming out nonzero

Tags: java, floating-point

I have this java code to calculate the sin(360):

```
if(re.equals(" sin "))
{
    try{
        String next=data.get(i+1);
        v1 = Double.parseDouble(next);
        double degreess = v1;
        double radianss = Math.toRadians(degreess);

        BigDecimal bDecimal1 = new BigDecimal(
            Math.sin(radianss), MathContext.DECIMAL32);

        re=""+bDecimal1;
        //re=""+Math.sin(Math.toRadians(Double.valueOf(next)));
        i++;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I expect `sin(360)` should be exactly 0.

But my result is non zero: `-0.0000000000000002449294`.  Why is this not zero?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961900/java-strange-behavior-with-sin-and-toradians
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566512/getting-value-of-sine-180-as-1-22465e-16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always use a decimal format:

```
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat();
format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
System.out.println(format.format(bDecimal1));
```

Comment: Why downvote this? It's perfectly valid to use a formatter to quickly round to desired decimal places.

Answer (score 4):

When dealing with floating point values, you should use `abs(sin360 - 0) < delta` (where delta is quite small like 0.0000001) instead of `sin360 == 0`. It's floating point internal representation issue.
[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Why would you recommend evaluating this comparison? The code in the question does not contain any floating-point comparison, and the question makes no mention of wanting to compare floating-point values. There is nothing here to indicate the questioner wants to make such comparisons. They are asking why they got a value they did not expect. Evaluating the comparison you suggest does not change the value to one they expect or otherwise improve floating-point accuracy. It serves no purpose in this context.